# Bing used as a Geocode

Tags: python, bing, geocode

Try to use Bing as a Geocoder, have done it successfully but when trying to do a batch, only displays one result.  Here is the code:

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.bing([df['Address']], method='batch', key='XXXX')
for result in g:
print(result.latlng)
```

The df used only contains addresses from Cheesecake Factory as an example (only 4) and is in a column called "Address".  It correctly displays the first one in the df.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiyp6.png)

Comment: What language is this? Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
from geopy import Bing
geocoder = Bing(api_key='insert key here')
df['bing_locations'] = df['Address'].apply(geocoder.geocode)
df
```